# Is there any way to add multiple dictionaries to a JSON file

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, dictionary

I tried adding an array with dictionaries into a JSON file, but it returns a bunch of errors, so I'm wondering if is it possible to add dictionaries into a JSON file.
(I'm not trying to push data into the JSON file using Node.JS, I'm trying to manually put dictionaries into the JSON file)

landmarks.json:

```
{
    "Isle of Dreams": {
        "name": "Isle of Dreams",
        "description": "An island surrounded by mist and myth, here dreamers come to fulfill their deepest desires."
    },
    "the Temple of Shadows": {
        "name": "the Temple of Shadows",
        "description": "",
        "droptable": [
      { id: 0, weight: 0.2, item: "Lemon" },
      { id: 1, weight: 0.3, item: ['Grape', 'Orange', 'Apple'] },
      { id: 2, weight: 0.4, item: 'Mango' },
      { id: 3, weight: 0.1, item: 3 }
  ]
 }
}
```

Error:
[image: description?]

Comment: Did you read the error messages lol

Comment: What's unclear about "Property keys must be doublequoted"? The same goes for array string values, which will get rid of the "Value expected" errors. The [JSON specification](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) fits on a napkin. I suggest reading it.

Answer (score 0):

#### The JSON file needs `"` symbols around the keys:

For example,

```
{ id: 0, weight: 0.2, item: "Lemon" },
```

should be

```
{ "id": 0, "weight": 0.2, "item": "Lemon" },
```

That is what the error messages are trying to tell you.

#### It needs double-quotes, not single-quotes, around strings

Not

```
 { id: 1, weight: 0.3, item: ['Grape', 'Orange', 'Apple']
```

but

```
 { "id": 1, "weight": 0.3, "item": ["Grape", "Orange", "Apple"]
```

#### Explanation

Inside Javascript *itself*, we are allowed to use the shorthand notation of dropping the `"` around keys, but we must remember that:

- when we want to write JSON, we need to put those `"` back in, and they have to be double-quotes, not single quotes `'`, and
- if we want to put in a variable for the key, we need to put square brackets around the key

Answer (score 0):

You should change your JSON like this:

```json
{
    "Isle of Dreams": {
        "name": "Isle of Dreams",
        "description": "An island surrounded by mist and myth, here dreamers come to fulfill their deepest desires."
    },
    "the Temple of Shadows": {
        "name": "the Temple of Shadows",
        "description": "",
        "droptable": [
            {
                "id": 0,
                "weight": 0.2,
                "item": "Lemon"
            },
            {
                "id": 1,
                "weight": 0.3,
                "item": [
                    "Grape",
                    "Orange",
                    "Apple"
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "weight": 0.4,
                "item": "Mango"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "weight": 0.1,
                "item": 3
            }
        ]
    }
}
```